# Python 3.9 で xml.etree.ElementTree モジュールが見つからない

Tags: python, python3, docker

ローカル環境にDockerコンテナを立ち上げました。
Dockerfileでは、下記のようにPython2.7と3.9をインストールしています。

```
pyenv install 3.9.10 && \
pyenv install 2.7.14 && \
pyenv global 3.9.10 && \
pyenv rehash
```

コンテナ内で、"ElementTree.py"を検索した際に、python2.7のディレクトリしかヒットしませんでした。

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py
```

Python3.9.10をインストールしましたが、なぜpython2.7のディレクトリしかないのでしょうか？

ちなみに、.pyenv ディレクトリには両方ありました。

```
/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py
/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py
```

Comment: 状況の前提として一つのイメージに2つの版数を共存させる必要があるのでしょうか？ それぞれの版数専用に別々のイメージを用意すれば問題は発生しないか単純化されるのでは？

Comment: `/usr/lib64/`以下にあるのはプリインストールされているPythonのもの、`/.pyenv/versions/`以下にあるのは`pyenv`によってインストールしたPython 2.7.14と3.9.10のものだったりしませんか？